# Kubernetes pod stays in Init phase

Tags: kubernetes

I am having problems with some pod staying in init phase all the time.

I do not see any errors when I run the `pod describe` command. This is the list of the events:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age              From                                                   Message
  ----     ------     ----             ----                                                   -------
  Normal   Scheduled  5m               default-scheduler                                      Successfully assigned infrastructure/jenkins-74cc957b47-mxvqd to ip-XX-XX-XXX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.internal
  Warning  BackOff    3m (x3 over 4m)  kubelet, ip-XX-XX-XXX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.internal  Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   Pulling    3m (x4 over 5m)  kubelet, ip-XX-XX-XXX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.internal  pulling image "jenkins/jenkins:lts"
  Normal   Pulled     3m (x4 over 5m)  kubelet, ip-XX-XX-XXX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.internal  Successfully pulled image "jenkins/jenkins:lts"
  Normal   Created    3m (x4 over 5m)  kubelet, ip-XX-XX-XXX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.internal  Created container
  Normal   Started    3m (x4 over 5m)  kubelet, ip-XX-XX-XXX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.internal  Started container
```

I can see this also:

```
  State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 23 Sep 2020 09:49:56 +0200
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Wed, 23 Sep 2020 09:49:06 +0200
      Finished:     Wed, 23 Sep 2020 09:49:27 +0200
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  3
```

If I list the pods, it looks like this:
`Error from server (BadRequest): container "jenkins" in pod "jenkins-74cc957b47-mxvqd" is waiting to start: PodInitializing`

But I am not able to see the specific error. Can someone help?

Comment: `kubectl get events` in this namespace

Comment: Please provide the logs by executing: `kubectl logs ${POD_NAME} ${CONTAINER_NAME}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official documentation has several recommendations regarding [Debug Running Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/):

- [Examining pod logs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/#examine-pod-logs): by executing `kubectl logs ${POD_NAME} ${CONTAINER_NAME}` or `kubectl logs --previous ${POD_NAME} ${CONTAINER_NAME}` if your container has previously crashed
- [Debugging with container exec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/#container-exec): run commands inside a specific container with `kubectl exec`: `kubectl exec ${POD_NAME} -c ${CONTAINER_NAME} -- ${CMD} ${ARG1} ${ARG2} ... ${ARGN}`
- [Debugging with an ephemeral debug container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/#ephemeral-container): Ephemeral containers are useful for interactive troubleshooting when `kubectl exec` is insufficient because a container has crashed or a container image doesn't include debugging utilities. You can find an example [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/#ephemeral-container-example).
- [Debugging via a shell on the node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/#node-shell-session): If none of these approaches work, you can find the host machine that the pod is running on and SSH into that host.

You can find more details in the linked documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I have used `kubectl logs jenkins-df87c46d5-52dtt -c copy-default-config -n infrastructure` 

For some reason `--previous` flag didn't work. 

Also, I was not able to `exec` command on the pod. When I try `kubectl -n infrastructure exec -it jenkins-5589d85c76-9tvj5 /bin/sh`, I am getting `error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("jenkins")` error.

Comment: --previous saved me as well :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I revealed the logs from the broken instance

`kubectl logs jenkins-df87c46d5-52dtt -c copy-default-config -n infrastructure > debug1.log`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't access the logs you can run the container as an interactive pod an follow the logs directly via

```
kubectl run --rm -it jenkins --image=jenkins/jenkins:lts -n YOURNAMESPACE
```

`--rm` ... delete the pod after it terminates

`-it` ... enable interactive and tty support

`-n` ... specify the target namespace

`--image` ... specify the image to use